# How to change the text of a rendered alert?

Tags: jquery, alert

I'm new to this, but maybe someone can help me. I am working on a site which renders alerts like this one: "Shipping option selected successfully." and: "ERROR: Discount code used is either invalid or expired." Now i have to translate these popup alerts into other languages. Is there a way to do this with jquery?

These messages are rendered in the cart on my shop. Here's a link to the site:

http://grootaartseuronics.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Comment: Post some of the relevant code. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: This is basic javascript. Please search google before posting a question.

Comment: Please don't expect users to reverse-engineer an external page. Post an example in your question.

Comment: @Dom I don't think he explained it clearly at first. It's not basic at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this !

‘ test1 = Browser("myBrowser").Dialog("Windows Internet Explorer").Static("alertbox").GetROProperty("text") ‘

(myBrowser --- Sample Browser title.)

Answer (score 0):

If the System used doesn't provide some kind of Localization System, you have to go through the source files and change the alerted text manually. 
See this here on how alerts work in JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp
A quick way to find the specific lines where this happens would be to use a [file search tool](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) and use it to look for the Text that is alerted. 
If the System uses some kind of Scripting language like PHP you may end up with modifying Variable Contents.